# How to stop ListView from scrolling automatically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Very trivial problem.
Super simple code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(color: Colors.red, height: 1000),
        Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 1000),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It keeps snapping to the item instead of scrolling organically; any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @Maxouille I added a gif for you.

Comment: I tried it on Dartpad. It does not snap to next item for me.

Comment: @JigarPatel I have it running in a new app now; on iOS it's snapping.

Comment: It works fine for me on Android. Did you tried your app on Android emulator ? Maybe that's an iOS specific behavior ?

Comment: @OliverDixon I ran it on iOS, it isn't snapping. Are you using `physics: PageScrollPhysics()` somewhere?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I'm not no; this is super strange. It's a brand new project; only code extra is the above.

Comment: @OliverDixon Can you post your full code?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I posted the full app code.

Comment: @OliverDixon I ran your code, and it is working as expected (no snapping behavior)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad what Flutter version?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad ios?

Comment: @OliverDixon It doesn't really matter the version because your' code is absolutely fine.  I'm running on iOS 14.4

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I'm running ```Flutter 2.0.3``` I'm still seeing this issue on iOS.

Comment: Can you also give it a try on macOS?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I'm doing this on MacOS; M1.

Comment: Delete the `theme` to see if it works. There is sometimes weird things going on with that.

Comment: I meant can you run the app on macOS (as software), not on the machine itself.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad it's the simulator it's broken!! We found a bug with Flutter

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a scrollbug bug with Flutter + iOS Simulator 14.4.

Logged a bug with Flutter here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79641